Variety of meanings of the term "birth certificate"?
I have the impression that the term "birth certificate" does not have the same meaning in all of the states in the U.S.A. and I know that what it means in the Province of Manitoba is different from what it means in some states in the U.S.A. I suspect that all ten provinces in Canada follow nearly the same procedures with birth certificates in order to assure that the federal agency that issues passports will find them acceptable.
In North Dakota, where I was born, a "certificate of live birth", generally abbreviated to "birth certificate", is a document signed by someone who says that the birth of a certain person happened at a certain time and place within the state, and normally give the names of the person born and of the parents, and the sex of the person born, and some items of information about the parents, including their dates of birth and the state or foreign country in which they were born. If a person born within the state applies for a passport, what they use as proof of citizenship is a "certified copy" of the certificate of live birth. The original certificate is permanently kept by the state. I suspect most of the 50 states do things in about that way.
Some of the publicity about the disagreements over Barack Obama's birth caused me to suspect that the state of Hawaii does things differently. Obama was issued a "birth certificate" that repeated the information on the document originally signed by the person reporting that the birth had occurred, and was not a copy of it. Later, an exception was made to the policy of not giving people their "long form" birth certificates, which, if I understand correctly, are certified photocopies of the original document. Whether the original document was called a "birth certificate" I don't know.
In Manitoba, the document on which someone reports to the provincial government that a birth occurred is called a "birth registration", not a "birth certificate". But when the government gives a person a document attesting that they were born at a certain time and place in Manitoba, and when that document is used as proof of citizenship on a passport application, they call that document a "birth certificate" and it is not a copy of the birth registration, but iterates some of the information on the birth registration. At one point in my father's life, he had such a birth certificate that was a piece of paper with a seal, and at a later time he had another such birth certificate that was a laminated wallet-sized card. Today, such birth certificates are printed on a polymer with lots of anti-counterfeiting measures.
How much diversity exists among such systems and the terminology that goes with them?

In the US, there are agreements between the Federal government and the states regarding both birth and death certificates. The states are in charge of both kinds of certificates. However, there have been increasing Federal restrictions that limit the use of nonconforming procedures. The Bureau of Vital Statistics issues standard form for birth and for death, but they are not required, only recommended. Several states use alternative forms. Most births are attended by a medical professional, who signs the certificate. This is not required by law, since some births are "unattended."

A “birth certificate” is shorthand for a government issued document evidencing a person’s birth
Details differ, but they all work much the same way:

A declarant reports the birth to the relevant government office. The declarant is often the child’s parent but other people may be obliged to report as well or instead. This may be a paper form or an online form.
The government registrar records the birth in a government register. In advanced countries this is usually an electronic database. The original form may or may not be kept. If it is kept, it may only be in scanned form.
The registrar then returns the “birth certificate” which is generated from the information in the register and sends it to the declarant. They also generate a new one whenever an appropriate request comes through.

Note that, in many parts of the world this system doesn’t work effectively or doesn’t exist and this is a big human rights problems - a birth certificate is the foundational legal document that proves you exist.
Now, historically, this was all done on paper so there would be an ‘original’ birth certificate held in a paper file at the registry (or in even earlier times, at the parish church). From this the registrar would make official copies. In a sense, this hasn’t changed - the ‘original’ is always held in the registry and any that are out there ‘in the world’ are either official copies or (notarized) copies of those.
